# Simple reverse-proxy configuration with Traefik and docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I'm having some hard time with Traefik 2.x and its configuration options.
I have the following docker-compose.yml file which should:

1. Create Traefik container
2. Create Grafana container (a web dashboard listening on port 3000)
3. Make Grafana reachable via port 80 through Traefik acting as a reverse proxy

Contacting the machine's IP at port 8080 I can correctly see the Traefik dashboard.
However, at port 80 I receive a 404

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:

  traefik:
    container_name: "traefik"
    image: "traefik:latest"
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=frontend
      - --entrypoints.frontend.address=:80
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
    networks:
      - frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"

  grafana:
    container_name: "grafana"
    image: "grafana/grafana:latest"
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=frontend"
      - "traefik.port=3000"

networks:
  frontend:
    name: frontend
  backend:
    name: backend
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct edit to my configuration.
In the labels section inside the grafana container, it is needed to set a rule for Traefik in order to recognize the URL

```
- "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`myIPhere`)"
```

Where I have inserted the IP of my machine in the Host field
Now Traefik recognizes the rule and routes the traffic incoming on port 80 to port 3000 as expected.